# Folder & Files Upload through ftp C#

Tags: c#, upload, ftp, directory

i'm trying to learn something new about uploading through ftp connection to another host.
i know how to upload single file. but what if i want to upload full folder with its full subfolders and files that exists on it?

this is my one single file upload

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Upload("Test.txt");
    }

    public void Upload(string fileToUpload)
    {
       try
        {
            FileInfo toUpload = new FileInfo(fileToUpload);

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://127.0.0.1/" + toUpload.Name);
            MessageBox.Show(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory);

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Uploader", "3635451");
            Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            FileStream file = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);
            int length = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            while (bytesRead != 0);
            file.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

i google'd alot about uploading folder but i have just failed
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [WinSCP library](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library). It is free, and supports FTP as well as SFTP. I have found it easy to use, and works flawlessly.

The `PutFiles` method will process an entire folder, including sub-folders. It also has a `SynchronizeDirectories` method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you cannot.

You may be interested by libraries for doing such operations, if not you can look at their source code.

If you want to upload a folder you have to create the folder on your FTP and then copy each file one by one.

Example of a folder on local:

```
/Folder/File1.txt
/Folder/File2.txt
```

If you want to upload the folder "Folder".

1. Create directory in FTP
2. Open the FTP directory
3. Copy "File1.txt"
4. Copy "File2.txt"